# Intuition behind testing seasonality hypothesis

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, monte-carlo, seasonality, intuition

In [this](https://reasonabledeviations.com/2021/06/17/hypothesis-testing-quant/) post to prove the statistical significance of a statement about a seasonality of a timeseries (every april returns are high) the author simulates alternative paths using the Monte Carlo method to reject the null hypothesis. These alternative paths are made by shuffling returns.

It seems unintuitive that we could even be able to generate alternative paths, as in the past only one of all these permutations has actually taken place.

Is there a way to make these generated paths 'less random'? And if there is, can we somehow measure the closeness of artificial prices to the actual ones?

Comment: That analysis is erroneous for the reason you point to: the shuffling breaks more than the seasonality in the series.  It destroys all structure whatsoever, simulating a null hypothesis in which the return on any day is *completely independent* of the returns preceding it. Time series analysts cope with this by shuffling subsequences of the original series or by modeling the series parametrically, zeroing out the seasonal term, and generating realizations from that model. Consider reading [our threads about this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=time+series+simulation+monte+carlo).